# how to debug a null pointer exception in gradle.build

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, refactoring

I have this `gradle.build` groovy file:

```
task BL_generate_parallel_warmup(type: JavaExec) {
     if (project.hasProperty('serverversion')) {
        args(serverversion)
    }
    if (project.hasProperty('input_flavor')) {
        systemProperties['input_flavor'] = input_flavor
        print "gradle input_flavor" + input_flavor
    }
    jvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m"]
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    dependsOn resources_cleaner_bl
    systemProperties['isDummyRun'] = 'true'
    main = "astar.BlParallelGenerator"
}
```

after i refactor it to this:

```
def setSystemProperties() {
    if (project.hasProperty('serverversion')) {
        args(serverversion)
    }
    if (project.hasProperty('input_flavor')) {
        systemProperties['input_flavor'] = input_flavor
        print "gradle input_flavor" + input_flavor
    }
    jvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m"]
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}



//warm up

task BL_generate_parallel_warmup(type: JavaExec) {
    setSystemProperties()
    dependsOn resources_cleaner_bl
    systemProperties['isDummyRun'] = 'true'
    main = "astar.BlParallelGenerator"
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error:(121, 0) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyProject'.
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>
```

**Update**

I solved this by changing:

```
def setSystemProperties(project) {
        if (project.hasProperty('serverversion')) {
            args(serverversion)
        }
        if (project.hasProperty('input_flavor')) {
            systemProperties['input_flavor'] = input_flavor
            print "gradle input_flavor" + input_flavor
        }
        jvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m"]
        classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }



    //warm up

    task BL_generate_parallel_warmup(type: JavaExec) {
        setSystemProperties(project)
        dependsOn resources_cleaner_bl
        systemProperties['isDummyRun'] = 'true'
        main = "astar.BlParallelGenerator"
    }
```

how can I debug it in the intellij?

I pressed the run in debug and added a breakpoint to the gradle build and yet it doesn't stop anywhere.

I have tried "edit configuration" like this:

[image]
but it didn't make the code stop at breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference documentation for debugging in Gradle can be found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/create-run-debug-configuration-for-gradle-tasks.html

To create a debug configuration for a Gradle task, right click on the task in the Gradle tool window and select Create. You will be given options on how to configure the debug configuration.

Since you are using a task of type `JavaExec`, there is another option.
You could place a breakpoint in your main class, and configure a remote debug session within IntelliJ.
[image]

As the image is showing, I have create a Remote type debug configuration that is listening on port 5005.
Then in your `JavaExec` type task, you would add the `debug=true` option as shown here:

```
task runApp(type: JavaExec){
    classpath  file('c:/data/test')
    main = 'TestMain'
    debug = true
}
```

To debug into it, you would click the `runApp` task within the Gradle plugin in IntelliJ, then start the `Local_Port_5005` remote debug session and have the task stop at your breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: please see my printscreen added

Comment: I have updated the answer with an additional option to debug JavaExec type tasks, which I was able to validate and test myself (shown in the pictures).